# Reading path from file to \includepgraphics

Tags: graphics

Im trying to automatically create reports for a series of variables stored in csv. I also wanted to do this with the pictures, so my idea was to store the path in the variable and then simply use `\includegraphics{\var{img_path}}`. But looks like includegraphics treats `\var{img_path}` as a string, indeed the text turns green.

This is the code I used to create the variable:

```
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{:}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{data}{report_data.csv}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{data}{key}{#1}{value}}
```

And this is the code used to show the picture, I added `\ExplSyntaxOn` because I read it on other post, but still doesnt work.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{resources/images/imagen1.jpg}
    \caption{\var{imagen2}}
    \label{fig:image_name}
\end{figure}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The funny thing is that the caption works as expected: `Figure 1: resources/images/image2.jpg`

Im new to LaTex, other things to have in mind, the `\var{}` definition is in `main.txt`, where im trying to display the picture is in `sections/section1` and the resources folder is on the root, yes I also tryed using `../resources/images/image2.jpg`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are surely not the best thing to do. Please make a complete compilable example (for the image use `example-image`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing your `\var{key}` in a `\caption` will not work without a `\protect`, but using it inside `\includegraphics` should work. The reason it does not is probably related to the implementation of `\DTLfetch` in package `datatool`.

Replacing `\DTLfetch` with `\DTLgetvalueforkey` seems to do the trick.
The latter is similar to the former, only it sets a command to the fetched value (see [the documentation](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) of package `datatool`).

I'm not sure what you wanted to do but the following MWE shows how to read a filename from your database and pass it to `\includegraphics` and `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{:}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={key,value}]{data}{database.csv}

\newcommand{\showfile}[1]{%
  \DTLgetvalueforkey{\filename}{value}{data}{key}{#1}%
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{\filename}
    \caption{This is file \protect\filename.}
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}
\showfile{example}
%\showfile{imagen1}  % requires resource/images/imagen1.jpg
%\showfile{imagen2}  % requires resource/images/imagen1.jpg
\end{document}
```

where the contents of `database.csv` are:

```
example:example-image.png
imagen1:resources/images/imagen1.jpg
imagen2:resources/images/imagen2.jpg
```